# select by data and text as a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

trying to select element by its `data-x` value **and** its `text` as a variable
without success

```js
var x = 5;
$(`.texbtn[data-x="fweight" && text="${x}"]`).css('background', 'gold');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='texbtn' data-x='fweight'>5</div>
```

Comment: Console tells you the selector: `unrecognized expression: .texbtn[data-x="fweight" && text="5"]` there is no && in selectors

Comment: @mplungjan all solutions on your link use string and not  variable

Comment: the var is down to your literal. Just change the text to the ${} var: `\`.texbtn[data-x=fweight]:contains("${x}")\``

Comment: Your attempt was treating jQuery selectors like javascript statements. You could also use a filter

Comment: @mplungjan - you missed some quotes - "fweight"

Comment: No I did not. Try it. It does not need quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Console tells you the selector:

> unrecognized expression: .texbtn[data-x="fweight" && text="5"]

there are no && in selectors

Here is a correct selector and an alternative using filter

```js
var x = 5;
$(`.texbtn[data-x=fweight]:contains("${x}")`)
  .css('background', 'gold');

$('.texbtn[data-x=fweight1]')
  .filter(obj => $(obj).text=x)
  .css('background', 'silver');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='texbtn' data-x='fweight'>5</div>
<div class='texbtn' data-x='fweight1'>5</div>
```